# What to use for .live() in the future? .delegate() does not work as expected

Tags: jquery

as I read, the jquery .live() method will not be available in the future.
I have a function, which triggers a click for Dom inserted html:

```
$('.post_headl span').live( "click", function(){
            alert('###');            
});
```

This works fine. With .delegate() it does not work:

```
$('.post_headl').delegate( "span", "click", function(){
            alert('###');            
});
```

As I wrote above, the span and its parents are inserted by jquery. So I had to use .live().

What is the error in my .delegate() function?

I also tried this:

```
$(".post_headl").on("click", "span", function(event){
alert('###');
```

})

An had no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a broader ancestor, such as the body. One that exists on page load and isn't going anywhere and doesn't get replaced or moved.

```
$("body").delegate(".post_head1 span", "click", function(){...});
```

It would be preferable to use an ancestor that is closer to the elements that fire the events. For example,

```
<!-- not dynamic, never changes -->
<div id="content> 
    <!-- the following div is dynamic and gets pulled in later -->
    <div class="post_head1"><span>click me</span></div>
</div>
```

you would want to use

```
$("#content").delegate(".post_head1 span","click",clickHandler);
```

or `.on` if currently using 1.7.1+ and no need for backward compatibility

```
$("#content").on("click",".post_head1 span",clickHandler);
```

Comment: Good point scoping it as close as possible to the elements that will be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "on":

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(".post_headl").on("click", "span", function(event){
    alert('###');
});
```

If I have understood correctly, even the .post_headl element is inserted by jQuery. If that's the case, you should attach the listener to another element.

You can test it using the following code:

```
$(document).on(".post_headl span", "click", function(event){
    alert('###');
});
```

Comment: Changing to `.on` has nothing to do with the problem posted.

Comment: This would not work for dynamically-added elements, you must attach .on() to the document, then scope it to the desired selector.

Answer (score 0):

the jquery [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) documentation says to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: It also says you can use `.delegate` on the following line to future proof older versions.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to .live() (even for dynamically-added DOM elements) is .on() on the document:

For example:

```
$('.post_headl span').live( "click", function(){
            alert('###');            
});
```

would change to:

```
$(document).on('click', '.post_head1 span', function() {
    alert('###');
});
```